# Как написать сниффер с фильтрацией по типу пакета ?

Tags: c, сеть, c++, perl

Под Unix'ы! Какие библиотеки использовать? И функции? Каким образом осуществить подсчет входящих и исходящих пакетов на машине с заданным IP адресом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы начал *(и, вероятно, закончил на ней же)* свой поиск с библиотеки [**libpcap.**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpcap/)

Для создания снифферов и вообще `packet capture and analysis` вцелом - отличный вариант.

*У этой библиотеки также существует враппер `C++`, который может оказаться более удобным для использования* - [**libcappp.**](http://libpcappp.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать вы случайно не знаете как перехватывать arp пакеты ?

Comment: @pol Ну, если нужна сторонняя программа, то `wireshark` точно умеет. Если нужно реализовать схожую функциональность, то с помощью `libpcap` это возможно. *Будут трудности - копайте сорцы `wireshark'a`.*

Answer (score 1):

Если целью является только подсчёт пакетов, то ничего писать не нужно, надо просто поднастроить iptables:
[Вот тут примерно объясняется как пользоваться счётчиками](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/traffic-accounting-with-iptables/)

Если всё таки надо что-то более продвинутое то можно использовать tcpdump с пайпингом в скрипт на том же Perl, например.

Если этого нехватает, то для Perl есть [Net::Pcap::Easy](http://search.cpan.org/~jettero/Net-Pcap-Easy-1.4207/Easy.pod) и куча всяких обёрток, также я пользовался [NetFilter](http://search.cpan.org/~yanick/NetPacket-1.2.0/lib/NetPacket.pm), очень понравилось.

А уж если трафика сотни мегабайт и компьютер для анализа слабоват, то тут уже надо закатывать рукава и cадиться за C++.